# Uml class diagram alternative of map attribute

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Through searching I found that in UML, aggregation(assuming that it's used properly) can be used to represent attributes in a class.

For example,
[image]

(Assume column can stand alone)

Then, using such example, if I want to replace the attribute: Column[] with map to represent the column's name, would it be correct to use an association class just like below? (In case, I'm not willing to put the column name in Column class as an attribute)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Association classes are used with simple associations. They have m-1-1-n multiplicity. The shared aggregation (as you used) has no defined semantics (and I recommend to simply not use it unless you have a domain specific and documented use for it). It's simply better to put the intended multiplicity on either side of an association.

An association class connects two classes, adding attributes and/or operations. Your example is "unconventional" since Table/Column have a simple relation which would not need an association class. A general example is the Student/Lecture relation where you can put an association class in between to record exam results, times etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that is a valid way of modelling the fact that you have some sort of key string that can be used to identify a `Column` of this `Table`.

Using a `Map` is one if the many possible implementations, so it's not a real *equal to*.

The advantage of modelling using the Association Class is that your model remains at the more abstract functional level and leaves out implementation details.

BTW. I would use a **composition** instead of an **aggregation** for the association between `Table` and `Column`, as there is an obvious strong ownership relation and life-cycle dependency between the two.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the attribute `Column[]` with map to represent the column's name and you are not willing to put the column name in Column class as an attribute and assuming that you want to follow [UML specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/About-UML/) precisely then you'll produce the model shown below:
[image]

`Map<Key, Value>` is usually understood as an associative *container* that contains key-value pairs `Map.Entry<Key, Value>` with unique keys. The container is modeled by the directional aggregation from `Map<Key, Value>` to `Map.Entry<Key, Value>`.

`Map<Key, Value>` and `Map.Entry<Key, Value>` are *templates*. Clause 7.3.3.1 of UML specification says that:

> A template cannot be used in the same manner as a non-template Element of the same kind. The template Element can only be used to generate *bound* Elements or as part of the specification of another template.

According to clause 7.3.3.3:

> A TemplateBinding is a relationship between a TemplateableElement and a template that specifies the substitutions of *actual* ParameterableElements for the *formal* TemplateParameters of the template.

Thus we have two bound elements that have TemplateBinding (marked by <> keyword) relationships with their templates:

- `ColumnNames` which essentially is the name for `Map<String, Column>`
- `ColumnName` which essentially is the name for `Map.Entry<String, Column`

According to clause 11.5.1 of the UML specification:

> An Association classifies a set of tuples representing links between typed instances. An AssociationClass is both an Association and a Class.

`ColumnName` is AssociationClass representing the link between instances of `String` and `Column` classes. We use notation from clause 11.5.5, figure 11.35 to express that.

Finally, the directional composition association between `Table` and `ColumnNames` classes tells us that each instance of `Table` owns an instance of `ColumnNames`, i.e. set of column names.

Note that while `ColumnNames` and `ColumName` classes are usually hidden from the end-user by an implementation, they nevertheless exist.

I used [BoUML](https://www.bouml.fr/) to draw the diagram.